# Spring Interceptor Prehandle How to get actual request.getServletPath() instead of 'error' if error occurs

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If a rest api call is made by wrong parameters or wrong `httpmethod` , in `preHandle` method `request.getServletPath()` returns `"/error"` instead of **actual requested path**.. For example if a resource `GetMapping("/test")` is called with `POST` then request.getServletPath() returns `/error` instead of `/test`.. I need /test info

How can i get actual called resource path?

*Spring Boot Version = 2.1.7*

Thanks

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: @dassum there is no code...  if a resource GetMapping("/test") is called with Post then request.getServletPath() returns /error instead of /test.. I need /test info

Comment: Are you using spring-boot or old spring?

Comment: @SounakSaha Spring Boot 2.1.7

Comment: by default it gets the actual path in case of error. Did you add any custom configuration? can you share the full project? You can see my [example](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet) with the default configuration and run it

Comment: `/error` is the actual path as that is what is currently requested. You want to URL of the previous request. What is it you are trying to do? Looks like you are using the wrong component/tool to achieve something.

Comment: @M.Deinum why pre handle method returns "/error" ? I am using just this interceptor config and i got no custom error message class implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final HandlerHelper handlerHelper;
    public InterceptorConfig(HandlerHelper handlerHelper) {
        this.handlerHelper = handlerHelper;
    }
    Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(handlerHelper);
    }
}

Comment: Please don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable. It is showing `/error` because that is what is being intercepted. That is the URL/page that is being requested, probably after something went wrong in the resultion of the previous request.